# Looping through an array of URLS

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudkit

Hoping this is pretty simple and I'm just being a slow newbie. I have created an app that stores photos in an iCloud container. That works. Now I'm trying to list the photos from the container to display in my UI view.

List container contents:

```
    public static func loadRBPhotos() -> [URL]? {
        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: getDocumentDiretoryURL(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            return directoryContents
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

From my view I can see the urls fine:

```
Button(action: {
   print(photoFileController.loadRBPhotos()!)
}){
   Text("Load RB Photos")
}
```

Outputs an array of file urls:

```
[file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~RbPhotos/Documents/.XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.icloud, ile:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~RbPhotos/Documents/.XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.icloud, ile:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~RbPhotos/Documents/.XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.icloud, ile:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~RbPhotos/Documents/.XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.icloud]
```

But Im struggling with looping over this array to display:

```
ForEach(photoFileController.loadRBPhotos()!, id: \.self) { photo in
    Text(String(contentsOf: photo))
}
```

Error:
[image]

Any help is SUPER appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to get the photos to display?

Comment: Ideally yes - the above code was just trying to put the URLS in as text as a test. Once I can get the ForEach loop working I can easily display the photos.

Comment: What's wrong with the ForEach?

Comment: Sorry Aheze - just updated with screenshot of error

Comment: since loadRBPhotos() may take time , u better load them in a background queue, and then assign another variable to hold the arry of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an array of Text items containing the full path to each file URL, use code like this:

```
ForEach(photoFileController.loadRBPhotos()!, id: \.self) { url in
    Text(url.path))
}
```

Note that that will include the full directory tree to each file, and iOS directory names are long and cryptic. You might want to edit the path down to the top level directory name and the filename instead.